# Npm start won't work after successfully installing create-react-app. Error code Enoent Error number -4058

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package, create-react-app

Whenever I try to pull up my create-react-app on VS code the npm start won't work. I get this error message. Please help.

$ npm start
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\NucampFolder\3-React\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\NucampFolder\3-React\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-02T10_23_42_980Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you run npm start from the folder where the package.json is located. You might need to cd into that directory